# Provide static IP to docker containers via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to provide static IP address to containers. I understand that I have to create a custom network. I create it and the bridge interface is up on the host machine (Ubuntu 16.x). The containers get IP from this subnet but not the static I provided.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    networks:
     - vpcbr

  apigw-tomcat:
    container_name: apigw-tomcat
    build: tomcat/.
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8009:8009"
    networks:
     - vpcbr
    depends_on:
     - mysql

networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1
         aux_addresses:
          mysql: 10.5.0.5
          apigw-tomcat: 10.5.0.6
```

The containers get 10.5.0.2 and 10.5.0.3, instead of 5 and 6.

Comment: aux-address is used to manually inform the ipam-driver about IP addresses already in use in the network

Comment: How can i scale up either of these containers using 'docker compose up -d --scale container-name=3' when i have allocated a static ip to the service?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Note that I don't recommend a fixed IP for containers in Docker unless you're doing something that allows routing from outside to the inside of your container network (e.g. macvlan). DNS is already there for service discovery inside of the container network and supports container scaling. And outside the container network, you should use exposed ports on the host. With that disclaimer, here's the compose file you want:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

  apigw-tomcat:
    container_name: apigw-tomcat
    build: tomcat/.
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8009:8009"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6
    depends_on:
     - mysql

networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

Comment: How can you do it in version 3?

Comment: @Atr_Max At the moment, you cannot: "Note: Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only honored for version 2 at the moment." https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipam

Comment: @BMitch why do you recommend against static IPs? Is it a good idea for security for Redis, as assumed here? https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/986#issuecomment-404596974 Thanks so much.

Comment: @Ryan Static IP's won't improve security, you still need to open the same connections, and your containers will still run inside of a namespaced network where you only expose what you need. Static IP's will decrease flexibility, including the ability to do a rolling update of your application, not work in swarm mode, and make the container's configuration harder to copy between environments or similar containers. For the linked issue, you just need to listen on 0.0.0.0 inside the container.

Comment: @BMitch Thanks! I'll take your word for it. It sure will be easier than the headache of trying to set a static IP, which I haven't gotten to successfully work in the past couple hours.

Comment: @alvery I have the same issue, you need to use --force-recreate option because docker-compose doesn't apply config on already created network ( maybe a bug )

Comment: Static IPs are okay when working with Azure. Scaling is at the VM level with Azure not at the container level. A bit of sanity introduced if I might add

Comment: @BMitch Would you advise against this for the use case of a container SSH'ing to an external server protected by `hosts.allow`? Defining a specific subnet, I can easily add the defined subnet to the `hosts.allow`.

Comment: @nkmol yes, I would recommend against static container IP's for that. You don't even need a published port for outbound connections. The host.allow will point to the docker host, not the container IP.

Comment: Seems the `gateway` part is invalid in version 3.

Comment: @user218867 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose/39498534?noredirect=1#comment78522944_39498534

Comment: @BMitch Better to update the answer to highlight that IMHO.

Comment: Some applications require you to specify the IP of the reverse proxy in order to resolve the `X-Forwarded-For` header. I'd consider that a legitimate reason to have a static IP for the reverse proxy.

Comment: Seems version 3 is now working fine as well!

Comment: The latest versions of `docker compose` ignore the version in the compose file. If you use fields from the version 2 file format, they are parsed even if you specify the version 3 syntax. You will still not be able to use it with Swarm Mode, which is the only reason to use the version 3 syntax.

Answer (score 37):

I was facing some difficulties with an environment variable that is with custom name (not with container name /port convention for KAPACITOR_BASE_URL and KAPACITOR_ALERTS_ENDPOINT). If we give service name in this case it wouldn't resolve the ip as

```
KAPACITOR_BASE_URL:  http://kapacitor:9092
```

In above `http://[**kapacitor**]:9092` would not resolve to `http://172.20.0.2:9092`

I resolved the static IPs issues using subnetting configurations.

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  frontend:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:9.4.4
        networks:
            frontend:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    redis:
        image: redis:latest
        networks:
            frontend:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.6
        ports:
            - "6379"

    influxdb:
        image: influxdb:latest
        ports:
            - "8086:8086"
            - "8083:8083"
        volumes:
            - ../influxdb/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
            - ../influxdb/inxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
        networks:
            frontend:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4
        environment:
          INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED: "false"
          INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED: "true"
          INFLUXDB_USERNAME: "db_username"
          INFLUXDB_PASSWORD: "12345678"
          INFLUXDB_DB: db_customers

    kapacitor:
        image: kapacitor:latest
        ports: 
            - "9092:9092"
        networks:
            frontend:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
        depends_on:
            - influxdb
        volumes:
            - ../kapacitor/kapacitor.conf:/etc/kapacitor/kapacitor.conf
            - ../kapacitor/kapdb:/var/lib/kapacitor
        environment:
          KAPACITOR_INFLUXDB_0_URLS_0: http://influxdb:8086

    web:
        build: .
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: $RAILS_ENV
        command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        networks:
            frontend:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
        links:
            - db
            - kapacitor
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - .:/var/app/current
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@db
          DATABASE_USERNAME: postgres
          DATABASE_PASSWORD: postgres
          INFLUX_URL: http://influxdb:8086
          INFLUX_USER: db_username
          INFLUX_PWD: 12345678
          KAPACITOR_BASE_URL:  http://172.20.0.2:9092
          KAPACITOR_ALERTS_ENDPOINT: http://172.20.0.3:3000

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 21):

If you are never seeing the static IP address set, perhaps it could be because you are using "docker compose up".  Try using "docker-compose up".

When I use "docker-compose up" (with the hyphen) I now see the static IPs assigned.

```
networks:
  hfnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.55.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.55.1

services:
  web:
    image: 'mycompany/webserver:latest'
    hostname: www
    domainname: mycompany.com
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    networks:
      hfnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.55.10
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - '../honeyfund:/var/www/html'
```

I wasted a lot of time to figure that one out.  :(

Comment: This answer just solved an issue I was dealing with for over a week! 

Comment: This works for me. I think you have a typo in your yaml. Shouldn't it be `mynet` instead of `hfnet`?

Comment: @JackLeEmmerdeur this is a random string. You can call it whatever you want. This is then used in the name of the network

Comment: @BonisTech My comment was valid before larsks corrected the answer. Take a look at their edit from Aug 3.

Answer (score 2):

I realized, that the more convenient and meaningful way is to give the container a container-name.
You can use the name in the same docker network as source.
This helped me because the docker-containers had changing IPs and by this I can communicate with another container with a static name that I can use in config-files.