# Point host to Docker container with static domain name

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

I have setup a web service in a Docker container such that it only responds to HTTP requests made to http://pouac.localhost.

So, currently, when I want to test this Docker container, I have to manually add the IP address of that container to the `/etc/hosts` file of the host. This IP address changes from one run to another, so I need to get it every time with:

```
docker inspect mycontainer
```

... and then add it to `/etc/hosts`.

It works, but it's a real pain. I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it.

If I understand correctly, [Docker includes a DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/). So I guess I could try to point the host to the Docker DNS, and that would be a start... but I have no idea at which address runs the Docker DNS.

For information, the host is running Ubuntu 16.04, while the Docker containers are started with `docker-compose`.

Comment: You could also assign static ip address to the container as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add the following line at the end of /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 pouac.localhost
```

Secondly, expose the TCP port 80 of your container.
For this to be done, add something like that in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
ports:
    - "80:80"
```

Then, TCP port 80 will be exposed for each IP address of your host, so it will be exposed to TCP port 80 on 127.0.0.1, so connecting to http://pouac.localhost will connect to your container.

Comment: Simple but efficient.

Comment: Can it be easly done with other host port than 80? E.g 10080:80? I have many webapps on different ports

Comment: Yes, you may add as many lines as you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `--add-host` flag while running docker container
example

```
docker run --add-host=google.com:8.8.8.8 -td <image_name>
```

the hosts mapping will be appended to /etc/hosts of the container.

example

```
docker run --rm \
--hostname mycontainer \
--add-host docker.com:127.0.0.1 \
--add-host test:10.10.10.2 \
alpine:latest \
cat /etc/hosts
```

output

```
172.17.0.45 mycontainer
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10.10.10.2 test
127.0.0.1 docker.com
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your answer, this is not really what I need. I need to access the container from the host, not the opposite.