# docker-compose use other container as DNS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file like:

```
services:
  dns-server:
    # ...
  other:
    image: ubuntu
    dns: dns-server
```

Is there any way to make the `other` container use `dns-server` as its DNS server without hardcoding the IP of that container? Using the container name doesn't give me an error but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can map `53:53` on `dns-server` and then use `127.0.0.1` for the same. Else you can assign a static IP to your `dns-server` and then use that IP for the `dns`. See this thread for static IP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose