# docker: Assigning specific IPs to containers inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wanted to ask how do I assign specific IPs to a group of containers from one docker-compose file? E.g. is there a way to set for example:

```
container1 - 172.1.1.1
container2 - 172.1.1.2
etc.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provide static IP to docker containers via docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `--ip` option for `docker run`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings.

You need to create a custom network to use it. Example:

```
docker network create --subnet 172.1.1.0/24 mynet
docker run -d --name mycontainer --network mynet --ip 172.1.1.5 alpine sh -c "while true; sleep 10; done"
```

The container `mycontainer` has the IP address 172.1.1.5.