# Why docker-compose starts a new IP address?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Everytime that I start a docker-compose machine it starts in a new IP address and I wonder a couple things:

- Why?
- How does it know that it has already used Ip .0 and jumps to .1 and then .2 and so on?
- Is there any way to say: hey, don't move from IP x?

Thanks

I hope you can answer the why, cause it may explain the others. Please, refer to the documentation about it. Thanks

Comment: Because this is how docker designed it. Perhaps describe the problem this is causing you so that we could help you fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best documentation on this gets into the technical details. Networking in docker is implemented with libnetwork, and the IP address allocation is performed by IPAM. This is documented at: https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/master/docs/ipam.md

Containers each get a new IP address from the network pool by design, and it's a useful design. You don't want a different container suddenly appearing with the same IP address of a container you were previously connected too if you can avoid it. That could result in errors at best, or a malicious impersonation of a container at worst.

Every time compose creates a new container, even if that is a small update to an existing image or a change to the properties of a container that requires a recreate, it goes through the docker API's to create a new container, which goes through the IPAM process to get a new IP address from the subnet range.

Most importantly, none of this should matter at all. If you are using IP addresses to communicate between your apps, your app is probably not ready to use containers. Between containers, you should be using at least DNS, and preferably something like the swarm mode VIP or a kubernetes service that better handles short lived containers and rolling updates. DNS results can easily go stale with their caching property, pointing to containers that are no longer running. Whether you use DNS or a VIP/Service, leave this up to the container runtime/orchestration tool to handle for you, and just have your application resolve the name of the service rather than relying on the IP address directly.

Comment: Thanks, for you answer @Bmith. Can you add something about question 3? Because I do not find how can I clear Ip 192.168.99.100 so docker can use it again (no colusion case). Or do you prefer that i open a new question about how to ReleaseAddress (This API is for releasing an IP address) & ReleasePool. I do not find how to do it in the documentation you mention? Thanks again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244825/how-to-ask-docker-ipam-extension-api-about-the-ip-address-in-use

Comment: sergkondr's answer covers how to do it with compose. There's also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498534/596285

Comment: Is it posible to do it from the Docker Toolbox with a command? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

[BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220580/why-docker-compose-starts-a-new-ip-address/55221422#55221422) gave you answers why it works this way, here is an example of my docker compose with hardcoded IP. I believe, that it is not good practice, but in my case it was permissible solution(it was lab environment):

```
version: '2'

services:
  consul:
    container_name: consul
    image: consul:1.4.2
    networks:
      consul-dns:
        ipv4_address: 172.31.255.10
    environment:
      CONSUL_ALLOW_PRIVILEGED_PORTS: 1
    volumes:
      - ./config:/consul/config
      - ./data:/consul/data
    restart: on-failure
    command: "agent -data-dir=/consul/data -config-dir=/consul/config -dev -client 0.0.0.0"

networks:
  consul-dns:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.31.255.0/24
          gateway: 172.31.255.1
```