# What is the DB_URL has to be in docker and spring boot configuration?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I try to deploy spring boot jar on docker container. But Connection is failed.
The DB_URL in application.properties is like below,

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

I build mysql docker container with mysql image from docker hub which port number is 3306. When I execute the application jar file on localhost with the following command,

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar Spring-Blog-Jpa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

it works well without errors. The application can communicate the mysql docker container having port number 3306 on localhost. Next I make docker container of application with below Dockerfile,

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
ADD target/Spring-Blog-Jpa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar blog-app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dfile.encoding=UTF8","-jar","blog-app.jar"]
```

The application docker image is built successfully. But the container can not connect to MySQL Docker container at all. The exception is `connection refused`.
In localhost, the application Spring-Blog-Jpa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar can connect to MySQL docker container, But In application docker container connection to MySQL docker container failed. What does DB_URL have to be to connect the mysql container?

Comment: You can create a network and use for both containers as `sudo docker network create spring-db-network` and while running use `--network spring-db-network`

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749842/9381897).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can understand the process on docker cli. I have one more question. How about using eclipse docker tooling perspective? Please inform me how to create network on eclipse docker perspective.