# Docker container communicate with localhost

Tags: docker

Hi I am running two image in two different container. One service and another is ActiveMQ. Now on service I am using

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
```

The issue is here is service container can not reach to localhost:61616 of active mq container. Can you share me How I can achieve this? I think some external port mapping is there. I am not sure about that.

Comment: If what you want to achieve is just containers communication, check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749842/9381897).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container)

Comment: In the linked duplicate, the OP is asking how to let the guest Jenkins container access the web server in the host environment.  That matches what you are trying to do.