# How to translate bridge networks in docker compose v. 3.7

Tags: docker, docker-compose

With version 2 it was defined:

```
networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1
         aux_addresses:
          mysql: 10.5.0.5
          apigw-tomcat: 10.5.0.6
```

How to write the same configuration in docker-compose version 3.7?

Reference: [Provide static IP to docker containers via docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose)

Comment: I don't think it's changed.  Is there a specific problem you're having?  (Is there a reason you need this setup at all?)

Comment: I need some services on the network it different IP than the main server for network traffic filtering. The thing right now I am getting an error in line `gateway`

Comment: ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
networks.app-tier2.ipam.config value Additional properties are not allowed ('gateway' was unexpected)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replicate that configuration with a version 3 (or later) configuration file.  From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipam):

> **ipam**
>
> Specify custom IPAM config. This is an object with several properties, each of which is optional:
>
> - `driver`: Custom IPAM driver, instead of the default.
> - `config`: A list with zero or more config blocks, each containing any of the following keys:
>
>   - `subnet`: Subnet in CIDR format that represents a network segment
>
> **Note: Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only honored for version 2 at the moment.**

To achieve something similar, you could create the bridge network outside of `docker-compose` using `docker network create`, and then make use of it by configuring an `external: true` network in your compose file.

Answer (score 0):

With `version 3.9`, you can configure network settings in docker-compose.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
networks:
  mynet01:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/16
    attachable: true
```

For details, please check this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network-configuration-reference

---

You can also create a network from command-line

```docker
$ docker network create \
  --driver overlay \
  --ingress \
  --subnet=10.11.0.0/16 \
  --gateway=10.11.0.2 \
  --opt com.docker.network.driver.mtu=1200 \
  --scope swarm \
  my-ingress
```

and you can refer to this network in docker compose as below

```yaml
version: "3.9"
networks:
  network1:
    external: true
    name: my-ingress
```

We used `external: true` because network is already available.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#customize-the-default-ingress-network