# Docker Compose Set Linux Docker Host IP Address in Container's /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, networking, docker-compose

When using Docker Compose, how can we determine and set the IP address of the Docker host in the `/etc/hosts` file of the Docker container when the host is running Linux? I will like a hostname like `DOCKER_HOST` in the container to refer to the Docker host.

Docker for Linux does not yet support `host.docker.internal`, unlike Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac, so we need an alternative to this.

`--network host` cannot be used here because for my purpose `localhost` in the container must still refer to the container itself.

Docker Compose supports using `extra_hosts` to add a hostname-ip mapping in `/etc/hosts`, but I am unable to figure out how to automatically determine the host IP address to be used.

```
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        extra_hosts:
            - "DOCKER_HOST:X.X.X.X"   # <=== How do we automatically set this IP address?
```

Is it possible to do something like the following, where we do not have to manually define the Docker host IP address when starting the containers?

```
DOCKER_HOST=`command_to_get_host_ip` docker-compose up -d
```

Or can we set a static IP for the Docker host in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide static IP to docker containers via docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose)

Comment: @RajSrujanJalem Think I need static IP to docker *host* instead of to containers

Comment: You can use `-e` option to pass environment variables, or you wanted the command to get host IP ?

Comment: @Philippe Command to get host IP will be very useful here

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
DOCKER_HOST=$(python -c 'import socket;print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))') docker-compose up -d
```