# Docker-compose Giving static IP in network mode : bridge

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i just try to give a static ip 172.17.0.44 to this container , like this way,

but it's not working ,

how to give the static ip address with "network_mode : bridge"

bcoz i need to give 172.17.0 series ip for this container

i'm getting this 172.17.0 series ip when i put network mode bridge

```
version: '2.1'

services:
mysql_db:
  image: mysql:latest
  network_mode: bridge
    ipv4_address: 172.17.0.44
  volumes:
    - "./.mysql-data/_data:/var/lib/mysql"
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8555:8110
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass123
    MYSQL_DATABASE: testing
    MYSQL_USER: test
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

already there is a network with 172.17 series ip , so i'm looking to join the container with that default bridge network and get a static IP

Comment: This is what you need, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/39493490/8438982

Comment: Your `YML` file is not formatted properly, at least the one you provided here, and I assume its causing the error in the terminal.

Comment: yes bro but i need to give the ip 172.17.0.44 this one , ithe above link is working we can create and give the ip what ever we need but i want to set this ip only , when i try this it's saying the network is already taken like that way error , if we put network mode : bridge 
then it will automatically attaching the container into default network , in that default network i need static ip 
that's i'm trying

Comment: Why do you need to set this address?  From within Docker space you can use the Compose service name `mysql_db` as a host name (with the internal port 8110); from outside, you can use the host's name (and the published port 8555) and you generally can't reach the container-private address.  You don't need any manual network settings.

Comment: it's creating for just like test db server , our some application are using the 172.17.0.44 address for db connection so that's why looking to assign a static ip, also this 44 ip, in network-mode bridge is fine but if we do docker-container down , and again do up the db container ip is changing so trying to give a static ip for all the time

Comment: @VishalVijayan have you found a way to assign a static IP on the default docker bridge?

Comment: I think the only way is to use the legacy `--link` mode and use container name

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the network to be created as well:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    networks:
      db:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.44
    volumes:
      - "./.mysql-data/_data:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8555:8110
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testing
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test

networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.17.0.0/24
```

For more info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: no bro it's getting 
ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
this error 
bcoz there is already a network with 172.17 series so 
that's why it's getting this error ( if we change to 172.18 it will work ) 
i need to join the container with "network mode : bridge" that will join to 172.17 series ip
and put the static ip that's the challenge here, i think we don't need to create a network here ,just wanto to give the ip only bcoz already there "network mode" is bridge

Comment: Yes, that's quite possible if you already have another docker network. You can change IPs to `172.18.xxx.xxx`

Answer (score -1):

There’s an error in your yaml because `ipv4_address` is not a key of `network_mode`.

What you want is the following:

```
network_mode: bridge
networks:
  default:
    ipv4_address:
```

The `default` network is created if nothing is specified.

Comment: tried but saying ipv4_address is a string like that error

Comment: that's not possible with compose: `ERROR: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined`