# How do I fix the docker-compose.yml? expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

How do I fix the docker-compose.yml?  expected , but found ''

ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError:
while parsing a block collection
in "testnode.yml", line 11, column 7
`expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'`
in "testnode.yml", line 11, column 18

How can I fix this?

```
version: '3'

services:
  uip-dns:
    container_name: uip-dns
    working_dir: /build
    image: "alpine"
    ports:
      - "26668:26668"
    volumes:
      - {{build}}:/build:Z
    command: ./dns
    networks:
      nsb_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.167.233.2
  node:
    container_name: node
    image: "tendermint-nsb/node"
    ports:
      - "26656-26657:26656-26657"
    environment:
      - PORT=:27667
      - DB_DIR=./data100/
      - TCP_AD=tcp://0.0.0.0:27667
      - ID=100
      - LOG=${LOG:-tendermint.log}
      - UIP_CHAIN_DNS=http://uip-dns:26668
    volumes:
      - {{build}}:/tendermint:Z
    command: node --rpc.laddr=tcp://0.0.0.0:26657 --proxy_app=tcp://0.0.0.0:27667
    networks:
      nsb_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.167.233.233

networks:
  nsb_net:
   # external: true
   driver: bridge
   ipam:
     driver: default
     config:
     -
       subnet: 192.167.232.0/22
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{{build}}` is not valid for docker-compose.yml. That looks like a golang template that would normally be expanded before passing the file to docker-compose. You'll want to replace that with a string, or defined variable. E.g.

```
version: '3'

services:
  uip-dns:
    container_name: uip-dns
    working_dir: /build
    image: "alpine"
    ports:
      - "26668:26668"
    volumes:
      - ${build_dir:-./build}:/build:Z
    command: ./dns
    networks:
      nsb_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.167.233.2
  node:
    container_name: node
    image: "tendermint-nsb/node"
    ports:
      - "26656-26657:26656-26657"
    environment:
      - PORT=:27667
      - DB_DIR=./data100/
      - TCP_AD=tcp://0.0.0.0:27667
      - ID=100
      - LOG=${LOG:-tendermint.log}
      - UIP_CHAIN_DNS=http://uip-dns:26668
    volumes:
      - ${build_dir:-./build}:/tendermint:Z
    command: node --rpc.laddr=tcp://0.0.0.0:26657 --proxy_app=tcp://0.0.0.0:27667
    networks:
      nsb_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.167.233.233

networks:
  nsb_net:
   # external: true
   driver: bridge
   ipam:
     driver: default
     config:
     - subnet: 192.167.232.0/22
```

I also strongly recommend getting rid of all the fixed IP's for the subnet and containers. Those break portability, and the ability to scale, rolling update, and various other features. Use the published port and host IP address instead, or docker's DNS between containers, if at all possible ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498534/596285)).