# docker network? is it persistent?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Say you have multi host cluster setup (I have elasticsearch cluster)

each instance is running on docker, and using

`network_mode: host`

It works, but sometimes hosts ip changes (such as after machine reboot or router reboot). Then I need to modify all the ip information on docker setup.

Is there a way to avoid this `changing ip` problem when using multi host docker services?

- edit

Here's my compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
 es-log-00:
  build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
      - MEM=${MEM}
      - ENV=${ENV}
  container_name: es-log-00
  network_mode: host
  environment:
      - node.name=node-master
      - discovery.seed_hosts=node1,node2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-master,node1,node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - cluster.name=littlehome-log
      - network.publish_host=192.168.1.105
      - path.repo=["/var/nfs/elasticsearch"]

      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es-log-00/es-log-00.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es-log-00/es-log-00.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es-log-00/es-log-00.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es-log-00/es-log-00.key
      - action.destructive_requires_name=true


  volumes:
   - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
   - /var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   - /var/lib/elasticsearch-backup:/var/lib/elasticsearch-backup
   - /var/nfs/elasticsearch:/var/nfs/elasticsearch
   - /var/nfs/elasticsearch/certs:$CERTS_DIR

  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536



volumes:
  data-log0:
```

Here's my /etc/hosts file

```
192.168.1.105 node-master
192.168.1.110 node1
192.168.1.107 node2
```

Comment: why don't you use service-name instead?

Comment: can you elaborate? I assign host-name to each machine, and specify them in /etc/hosts and use the hostname inside docker-compose.yml file. still I need to fix `/etc/hosts` file for every machine..

Comment: can you give your compose file?

Comment: @HumayunM I added it in the op

Comment: You could also use regular DNS instead of manually editing the names into hosts files...

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose