# How to assign static ip for docker containers (docker compose) in windows WSL2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

I use docker compose to build up the services, i want to set the mysql to be static, i tried to use networks directive but it didn't work and the errors say the ip already occupied, every this i restart the windows, the mysql ip was changed, sometimes 172.18.0.3,or 172.18.0.4, anyone know how to assign a static ip to the container? here is the yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: hki_nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 4433:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf    
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./src:/var/www
    links:
      - php
      - php72
  php:
    container_name: hki_php
    image: php:5.6-fpm-ext1
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
      #- ./php/phpfpm/:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/
  php72:
    container_name: web_php
    image: php:7.2-fpm-ext2
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php72/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php72/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
      #- ./php/phpfpm/:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/      
  mysql:
    container_name: hki_mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*Abcd1234
      - MYSQL_USER=abc
      - MYSQL_PASS=*Abcd1234
    #networks:
        #default:
            #ipv4_address: 172.18.0.3
```

Comment: Youd could try [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose/52184320

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve], and include the actual error you get?  (Remove unnecessary containers, `volumes:`, archaic options like `links:`, and overrides like `container_name:`; include only the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the issue.)  It also might be helpful to explain why you're trying to manually set the IP addresses, since you shouldn't usually need to directly access them.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you commented the part that assigns a static IP to your mysql container

```yaml
 mysql:
    ...
    #networks:
        #default:
            #ipv4_address: 172.18.0.3
```

If you take away the `#`, it will have a static IP.

And you might have forgotten the top-level `network` section in your `docker-compose.yml` as the  [official doc setting static IP](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address) states

```yaml
networks:
  app_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/24
```

Comment: "but it didn't work and the errors say the ip already occupied"

Comment: I edited my response for a suggestion if you may try