# Pocketbase sdk not working in docker container with the container name as the hostname

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, fetch-api, pocketbase

I made an app using pocketbase and next.js.
I deployed each one in different containers, and i used **docker-compose** to build and run the containers.
The problem is when i try to get the data using **fetch api** with the container name **as the host name** like this:

```
 const data = await (
    await fetch(
      "http://" +
        (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? "sewing_api:8080"
          : "127.0.0.1:8090") +
        "/api/collections/models/records?page=1"
    )
  ).json();
  return {
    props: {
      models: data,
    },
  };
```

This is pocketbase logs:
[image]

It runs perfectly fine and i get a response. But when i use the pocketbase sdk like this:

```
const pb = new PocketBase(
        "http://" +
          (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
            ? "sewing_api:8080"
            : "127.0.0.1:8090") +
          ""
      );
const clients = await pb.collection("clients").getFullList({
        batch: "-1",
      });
```

I get these errors:
**GET http://sewing_api:8080/api/collections/clients/records?page=1&perPage=-1&batch=-1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**.

**Uncaught (in promise) ClientResponseError 0: Something went wrong while processing your request.**

and when i see pocketbase logs i don't find any request.

this is my pocketbase docker image:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG PB_VERSION=0.14.2


RUN apk add --no-cache \
    unzip \
    ca-certificates

# download and unzip PocketBase
ADD https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/releases/download/v${PB_VERSION}/pocketbase_${PB_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip /tmp/pb.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/pb.zip -d /pb/
# run migrations
COPY pb_migrations/ /pb/pb_migrations/
RUN /pb/pocketbase migrate
EXPOSE 8080

# start PocketBase
CMD ["/pb/pocketbase", "serve", "--http=0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

next.js docker image:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  sewing_api:
    image: "sewing_api"
    container_name: "sewing_api"
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  sewing_ui:
    image: "sewing_ui"
    container_name: "sewing_ui"
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I found this [article](https://github.com/pocketbase/js-sdk/issues/21) says Node17+ for some reason favors the opposite (IPv6 first, then IPv4) (I don't know if this even realated to my problem). but when he switched from `localhost:8090` to `127.0.0.1:8090` it worked so i wanted to give my container static ip and use it like this:

```
const data = await (
    await fetch(
      "http://" +
        (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? "sewing_api:8080"
          : "ContainerIpAdresse:8090") +
        "/api/collections/models/records?page=1"
    )
  ).json();
  return {
    props: {
      models: data,
    },
  };
```

but i read an answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose) says it is not recommended.
I searched a little about how docker container dns works and i found that Docker container has inbuilt DNS which automatically resolves IP to container names in user-defined networks. So it may be a network configuration issue.